# Is there a \notimplies symbol?

Tags: symbols

I'm looking for an `implies` symbol with a diagonal strikethrough, as `\notin` is to `\in`. The closest I've found so far is `\nRightarrow`, which is too short.

Comment: Also see [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764)

Comment: @Werner ...and I add my upvote for the best answers.

Comment: @Werner Think so, thanks.